# How is it possible to sort a D3 generated HTML table with no "transition()" call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, html-table, transition

I'm trying to understand how it is that a D3 generated HTML table can be transitioned without the explicit use of a D3 "**transition()**" call.

The original code is Mike Bostock's sortable table: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3719724

The bulk of the code reads data from a CSV file, maps it to different column heading names and renders an HTML table:

```
d3.csv("readme-states-age.csv", function(states) {
  var ages = d3.keys(states[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key != "State" && key != "Total";
  });

  d3.selectAll("thead td").data(ages).on("click", function(k) {
    tr.sort(function(a, b) { return (b[k] / b.Total) - (a[k] / a.Total); });
  });

  var tr = d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
      .data(states)
    .enter().append("tr");

  tr.append("th")
      .text(function(d) { return d.State; });

  tr.selectAll("td")
      .data(function(d) { return ages.map(function(k) { return d[k] / d.Total; }); })
    .enter().append("td").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 71)
      .attr("height", 12)
    .append("rect")
      .attr("height", 12)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d * 71; });
});
```

It appears that the sorting of the table happens with this "on click" callback:

```
  d3.selectAll("thead td").data(ages).on("click", function(k) {
    tr.sort(function(a, b) { return (b[k] / b.Total) - (a[k] / a.Total); });
  });
```

I see the "**sort()**" function being called on the resulting selection of data records (tr) but I don't understand how the transition is actually being applied to resort the table.  It just seems to happen.

Can someone please explain how and why the sorting can be achieved without an explicit call of the **d3.transition()** function?

Comment: `.transition()` simply adds animation to a change in the state of a selection. There's no animation in the example (no change of state, either), so there's nothing to transition.

Comment: Not only there's no transition, but also, if you actually wanted a transition (i.e. `<tr>`s literally animating to their new positions), it would take a whole lot of work to achieve that.  In fact, you wouldn't use a table in that case; you'd have to absolutely position every row at some position, which you'd have to calculate yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There are 50 states - the below code creates 50 rows and binds each one of the 50 lines to 50 rows individually (Each row contains the value for value for the different age buckets)

```
var tr = d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
         .data(states)
         .enter().append("tr");
```

The onclick function gets passed in the name of the column header ( 5-13,14-17  ,18-24...) - the sort function returns the value in descending order for the column clicked which inturn sorts the entire row.

```
d3.selectAll("thead td").data(ages).on("click", function(k) {
    tr.sort(function(a, b) { return (b[k] / b.Total) - (a[k] / a.Total); });
  });
```